# How to configure Jmeter to handle www-authenticate: Negotiate header 'kerberos'

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I need to performance test a SSO based application which uses Kerberos authentication.
In my jmeter tool I have added `Http Authorization manager` and configured `krb5` and `jaas config` files in bin folder.

While re-playing I am getting '401' and the response header contains 'www-authenticate: Negotiate'.

This was handled by the browser and the Load runner tool.
In load runner, after configuring krb5.ini file, I was able to get the access token.

Can anyone tell me how to generate this Negotiate token in jmeter

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to select `KERBEROS` as the "Mechanism" in the [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)

   [image]
2. Provide all other values like username, password, domain and realm
3. Make sure to use `HttpClient4` implementation under [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

   [image]
4. `krb5.conf` and `jaas.conf` settings must match your application setup
5. You might also want to set [`sun.security.krb5.debug`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/Troubleshooting.html) property to `true` under *system.properties* file of JMeter installation and inspect messages in the console

More information: [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/)